# Create a two column layout with a vertically expanding container

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create a two column layout (CSS only, no javascript).

There are a few requirements that make this complicated:

1. Container starts with a specific height (e.g. `200px`)
2. There are two columns
3. Items fill Column 1, then if more space is needed fill Column 2.
4. If Column 1 & Column 2 are full, then expand the height of the container.

Detailed example [here](http://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/VPPrab?editors=1100).

**Bad**
[image]

**Good**

Elements first fill Column 1:
[image]

Next, elements fill Column 2:
[image]

When the container's minimum height is reached, the container expands and elements reflow between the two columns:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox + CSS columns gets you really close...

http://codepen.io/simshanith/pen/ZLLvGB?editors=1100

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <!-- etc. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}

.columns {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid;
  /* IE 10+ */
}
```

However, the first column is not filled to 200px. CSS Columns optimize for shortest, so the second column will appear with at least 2 items.

Answer (score 2):

With flexbox, you can expand the container vertically when `flex-direction` is `row`. As you have noted, however, this lays out flex items horizontally – left-to-right (in LTR writing mode) and then back, like an old typewriter.

In `flex-direction: column`, items are laid out top-to-bottom, and the container expands horizontally.

What you want – for columns to stack top-to-bottom, expanding the container vertically (like the Pinterest layout) – is not currently possible with flexbox.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is it possible with any other CSS (doesn't need to be flexbox)?

Comment: Try CSS Grid Layout. See the duplicate post for more details.